# What is the lifecycle of a converter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, lifecycle, converters

What is the lifecycle of a converter?
When you make a converter derived from `IValueConverter` and `IMultiValueConverter`, the class is not static nor are the `Convert()` and `ConvertBack()` functions.  So what is the lifecycle of that class instance?
If I use the converter in XAML in more than one Binding, is a new instance of the class created for each control?  Or is a new instance of the class created each time the Binding is updated?  Or perhaps is there only one instance for the entire application?

Comment: It depends on how you define the converter. Please show how you do this and how you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifecycle of a converter is in general the same as any XAML object instance and depends on the declaration. Usually a converter is declared as a resource of a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverterx:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

In this case, the converter (or the resource in general) is reused for every reference to it. This is because of the [`x:Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute) attribute. This attribute is `true` by default, which instructs the XAML parser to reuse the instance of the object. You can set it explicitly to `false`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverterx:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" x:Shared="False" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Now every time the resource is referenced the XAML parser creates a new instance.

If you declare the object outside a `ResourceDictionary`, the behavior of the XAML parser is different. You can assign object instances to a property like above, as a resource. But you can also use [Property Element Syntax](http://Property%20Element%20Syntax) instead, to instantiate a XAML object:

```
<Binding Path="Values">
    <Binding.Converter>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
    </Binding.Converter>
</Binding>
```

This declaration results in a converter instance, that is only used for this particular binding (or property). This declaration doesn't reference a resource (using either [`StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources#static-and-dynamic-resources)) but explicitly creates an instance that is exclusively assigned to a property (in this case `Binding.Converter`).

As a side note:
[`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources#static-resources) does not mean that the resource is static. It's a markup extension that instructs the XAML parser to lookup the resource tree to find a predefined instance. Same does [`DynamicResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources#dynamic-resources). The only difference is that `StaticResource` instructs the XAML parser to resolve the reference to a resource at compile time, whereas `DynamicResource` let's the XAML parser create an expression instead, that will be evaluated at run time. `DynamicResource` therefore resolves the resource at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The instance number of converter depend on your code.You can try this code yourself:

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ConverterTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConverterTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ToStringConverter x:Key="StaticToStringConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="Slider"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Slider,Path=Value,Converter={local:ToStringConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Slider,Path=Value,Converter={local:ToStringConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Slider,Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource StaticToStringConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Slider,Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource StaticToStringConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace ConverterTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml 的交互逻辑
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    sealed class ToStringConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();


        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(guid);
            return $"{guid.ToString()}:{value.ToString()}";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private ToStringConverter _converter;
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (_converter == null)
            {
                _converter = new ToStringConverter();
            }
            return _converter;
        }
    }
}
```

The Result picture as below:
[image]